# Does storing code in header files cause memory management issues in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, header-files

Not so long ago one man told me that storing all the code in .h files produces some memory management issues. Because I get too many duplicates of one class. And I'll avoid this issue if I'll store a code in .h/.cpp files. Is that true?

I've already googled some info on this subject and I read that it's all just about habit. So what about memory problems in case of storing all the code in .h files?

Comment: What please? I don't understand what you're asking about.

Comment: There is no memory problem, but there's a name pollution problem, that you don't have a compiler firewall available. And that in turn means that there's a problem with circular module relationships. With a compiler firewall the implementation of A can depend on the interface of B and vice versa, with these as separate modules, but with pure header modules you have to fudge it somehow.

Comment: Well, if you try to include  some code from a header twice that could cause some problems, that's why you should use include guards. But except that there are no other problems on that. For example, a lot of boost libraries are header-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... one man told me that storing all the code in .h files produces some memory management issues. [...] And I'll avoid this issue if I'll store a code in .h/.cpp files. Is that true?

Memory management usually refers to handling of dynamic memory at runtime. For clarity: Writing all your code in headers has nothing to do with that. However, doing so may increase the amount of memory that the compiler uses indeed. So, if that's what the *one man* meant, then yes, it could *potentially* be true - but it's not the biggest problem with the approach.

> Because I get too many duplicates of one class

This is a silly argument. In fact, using only header files for definitions means that there is exactly one translation unit where the class definition is included exactly once.

The potential problem is that your single translation unit includes all definitions in all header files. Since everything is processed in one go, the maximum memory required by the compiler is potentially higher. It's probably insignificant to most projects, but for something like libreoffice, it could probably become a problem.

---

A bigger problem with defining all functions in headers - i.e. using a single translation unit - is that any change to any header, however small, will cause the single massive translation unit to change, and you'll be required to compile it again. With multiple, *smaller*, translation units, only ones that are affected by the change will need recompilation.

So, the problem with your approach will be that every recompilation is as slow as compiling from scratch. Sure, if the compilation takes a minute, it doesn't matter, but for projects that take hours to compile from scratch, this is essential.

Comment: I think "too many duplicates" refers to inline functions - there are many copies of them in different translation units, which the linker should throw away (except one). So, the part about "exactly one translation unit where the class definition is included exactly once" is wrong - it's exactly the opposite - because class definition is included in many translation units, there are all these identical inline functions, which should be taken care of.

Comment: @anatolyg if all code is in headers, then where do these **different translation units** come from?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I have never used code entirely in header-files, with only one translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Your "one man" doesn't know what he's talking about.

Use of header files can only (potentially) cause the compiler (or programs that implement phases of compilation) to consume more memory during compilation.   That depends on how the compiler is implemented though.  And a quality compiler will deal with it.   If some compilation unit has enough code to cause a compiler to run out of memory then that's another concern .... and largely unrelated to use of header files.

If you write code that causes memory management concerns in your program, putting that code into header files makes no difference - bad code will cause a program to have memory management concerns (leaks, using dangling pointers, etc) regardless of whether parts of that code is in header files.

If header files are used carelessly, there are some situations where multiple object files can each contain a definition of some functions.   Technically, this can increase memory usage of a program, but there are also coding techniques to mitigate that - albeit some details of the techniques may differ a little if using header files.   In other words, it is writing poor code that makes the difference, not (on its own) putting code into header files.

There are other concerns with use of header files (or the preprocessor more generally).   But there are benefits to using header files, and techniques to manage such concerns.  And those concerns are practically unrelated to memory management issues anyway.

Practically, it is usually better to split code sensibly between header files and compilation units (aka .h and .cpp files).   But there are also cases where putting function definitions for a library in header files are beneficial (e.g template libraries).